# JavaFX and maven: NullPointerException: Location is required

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have been trying to get Maven set up with JavaFX. Even though I was unexperienced with Maven and JavaFX, I didn't expect it to be so much of a challenge. My Java knowledge is pretty solid (including Swing), and didn't expect to have this much difficulty getting it set up.

I started with a JavaFX project supplied by IntelliJ 13.0 Community Edition. The code in my Main class is relatively small:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        //getClass().getResource("../../resources/sample.fxml");
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and my `pom.xml` isn't too big either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaFXDemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <organization>
        <name>RubberDucky</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm using the [JavaFX Maven Plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/) to build the application. After running `mvn clean jfx:jar` everything seems fine, all builds succeed. But when I try to run the application I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:15)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

After some rough debugging the trouble seems to be in the path I am loading my files from. After hardcoding the `sample.fxml` to a place on my hard drive, the application runs without any problems. Same goes for the current setup (seen above) when running the application from IntelliJ.

I feel like I have exhausted every resource (including StackOverflow, some very similar errors) but I just can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: `getClass().getResource("../sample.fxml")` is null. Maybe try  `getClass().getResource("resources/sample.fxml")` or `getClass().getResource("/resources/sample.fxml")`?

Comment: `getClass().getResource("../sample.fxml")` works in the debugger, just not in Maven. I have tried your suggestions but neither work and I just can't figure out what would.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Make sure that your `sample.fxml` is in the `src/main/resources/` directory (or a subdirectory). Then you can access the file like this:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

**Explanation**: 
During the compile phase all resources and classes get copied to `target/classes/`. So your fxml file resides in this directory and your class in a subdirectory regarding its package name. If you call `getClass().getResource("sample.fxml");` the file will be searched relative to the class file which will be this directory: `target/classes/sample/`.

Calling `.getResource()` on the classloader sets the relative search path to `target/classes/` and therefore your file gets found.

P.S. You could also write:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I've had issues with java paths for a while and your clear explanation fixed both my problems and the issues.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind  But I have a more than one Build runs. Some of them dont use the fxml's of the other builds, so I dont want to include all my fxml's into all of my builds! My Window is under "views/ClientWindow.fxml" and my Main is under "controllers/Main.java". Somehow I can't seem to get it to work... very annoying.

Answer (score 16):

As @Absurd-Mind already explained, maven will not copy any resource files (like fxml) which resides under the `src` directory.

If you want to keep the `fxml` files besides the java source files, you can use the maven resource plugin to copy them:

```
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
            </includes>             
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: Love it. This is finally the answer. I'm plagued with this error for FXML now that its a Java 11 world! @mrak

Comment: You saved my day ... i really needed this, otherwise it was not getting executed on mvn clean install. It worked for me.

But I have a query here, well if we get the jar, i was thinking everything should go in to jar and nothing else should be visible to outsiders so that i can just have one file to execute, how to acheive this? any help on this is appreciated

Comment: After adding maven framework my javafx this worked. I also added the .css file just like the fxml.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with Intelij and Gradle.

Steps to fix:

1.Move file

> sample.fxml

to path

> \src\main\resources\fxml

2. Set path on this file:

> Parent root =
>   FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 likes this answer, especially since it automatically puts .fxml files in this directory.

Answer (score 3):

For those who use **gradle** as their build system add this to your `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets.main.resources {
    srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]; //assume that your java classes are inside this path
    exclude "**/*.java"
}
```

Then clean and rebuild your project.

So what will it do? If you have a `view.fxml` inside your `com.example.myfxapp` package, after building your project it will exported to `<build dir>/resources/com/example/myfxapp/view.fxml`

Answer (score 0):

For me I had took care of following things -

1. Make sure fxml file is placed where your main class resides. And then load it using this - (In my case, TechJFX.fxml is the file)

   ```
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TechJFX.fxml"));
   ```
2. Add opencv-*.jar to your project folder (In my case opencv-300.jar)
3. Add the jar to the build path using

Right click on the project folder -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries Tab -> Add External JARS and locate the jar

Also, under Order and Export -> Tick opencv-300.jar and JRE System Library(if not already ticked)

4. Copy opencv_java*.dll (In my case opencv_java300.dll) to the same location where you jar is in the project folder.
5. Add the following method to your main class

   ```
    static{ 
           System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
      }
   ```
6. Done.

Hope this helps someone facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

my case is installed the javafx sdk to `C:\Program Files\Java\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk`.

And root cause is the the space contained in the sdk path name.

Fixed by install the javafx sdk to folder which name without space, such as `C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar exception in my Application.
This is how I solved it The application is using the WinPcap 4.1.3 library, I installed it on my computer Exception disappeared
if your application uses a library and it is not installed on your computer, you must install it on your computer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).