# FXMLLoader won't find fxml file - Maven project

Tags: java, maven, javafx, fxmlloader

When I run the main class, in a Maven project, I get:

> Exception in Application start method

From what I've understood i'ts because the FXML file won't load.

**This is the Filesystem Hierarchy**

```
 src
    └- main
        ├- java
        |   └- zenit
        |      └- ui
        |         └- TestUI.java
        └- resources
            └- zenit
               └- ui
                  └- Main.fxml
```

In Eclipse (inside src)

[image]

[image]

Reading [apache's maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and [other statck questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000423/javafx-and-maven-nullpointerexception-location-is-required), following code-snippet seems to be the right way to create the `FXMLLoader` and point to the `Main.fxml` file.

```
public class TestUI extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));

        .
        .   // set controller, load parent, set scene etc.
        .

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But this code will throw the previously stated exception.

When I tried to pinpoint where in my code the `Exception` came from I figured out it was form the `FXMLLoader`.
So I ran the different sysouts (one at a time), on the line above `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(..)` :

```
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("main/resources/zenit/ui/Main.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("../../../resources/zenit/ui/Main.fxml"));
```

For all, the console output was: (obviously not expected output)

> null

So, my question are,

## Why does `.getResource("Main.fxml")` return `null` here?

## How do I correctly access the `Main.fxml` file in this case?

My system:

- *Maven: Apache Maven 3.6.0*
- *Java SE: 11.0.2*
- *JavaFX: 11.0.2*
- *Eclipse: 2018-12 (4.10.0)*
- *OS: macOS Mojave - v10.14.3*

Comment: try giving the package names in front of the "Main.fxml" in getResourse() method because the class TestUI and the fxml file are in different locations

Comment: I've updated my question.. Same thing.. :(

Comment: `package zenit.ui; ... class TestUI {}`. In eclipse the source directories must be java and resources for maven compliance. Look into the jar for the file `/zenit/ui/Main.fxml`

Comment: @Strazan try putting "../../../rescources/zenit/ui/Main.fxml" and see?

Comment: @JoopEggen I have java and resources no? Should I remove src and only have those?

I found the `Main.fxml`-file in the jar"

Comment: @DiliniPeiris same thing :/

Comment: @Strazan i might be saying a stupid thing.. but the spellings are wrong for "resources". both you and i have written "rescources" previously. correct that and see? because i once had this problem long time ago and it was a matter of correctly writing the package names

Comment: @DiliniPeiris haha jesus christ :P well unfortunately, still `null`

Comment: You may have other problems - typically when it cannot find the fxml - the exception will say "location not set"

Comment: For maven you have the correct hierarchy. If you open the jar with 7zip or whatever you should see `/zenit/ui/Main.fxml`. In fact you might also use an absolute path `getResource("/zenit/ui/Main.fxml")`. (It _just_ might be that somehow the maven project build is not configured correctly in eclipse.) Check the jar

Comment: @JoopEggen I do see the `Main.fxml` inside the jar under zenit/ui/ !! and when I use `getResource("/zenit/ui/Main.fxml")` sysout will print the path, and not `null`!! cheers! but I still get the exception tho :/

Comment: @EdvBeq any idea what the issue might be? :D

Comment: If you upload your project somewhere - I can take a look tonight.

Comment: @EdvBeq Thank you, that's very kind of you!

Here is the project, ( feature/maven2 is the branch. I'm trying to convert the project to maven. )
https://github.com/strazan/zenit/tree/feature/maven2

Comment: The Main.fxml evidently is found (the URL is not null). So the exception (which you did not list) must point to some (next) problem. Start with a simple fxml.

Comment: @JoopEggen alright, I don't get any stack traces. I wrote everything I got!! I tried with a new fxml now (a `pane` wrapped in an `anchorpane`) same thing :/

Comment: Hopeless, but try a sample Mave JavaFX application.

Comment: @JoopEggen yee!! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think your main problem is the library "ikonli." If you try to open the fxml with scenebuilder you will see the exception. My recommendation is that you lose that dependency. Use something simpler such as svg graphics:

   - In the fxml button > add a region > set the region size > then in the style section add the css property -fx-shape > and in the value set the svg path in quotes i.e.:  "M827.6 ... 122z"
   - Next add another css property -fx-scale-shape > and set its value to true

The above does not require any third party libraries and you can find all the icons for free online.

2. I recommend that you load your fxml from the main controller class. In the fxml check the property fxroot and add a constructor to your main controller like so

public MainController() {

```
try {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    loader.setController(this);
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.load();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

3. Your controller should extend the root container like so:

   public class MainController extends VBox {

then in the main class just pass the main controller to the scene

```
Scene scene = new Scene(controller);
```

4. I believe your maven project was not set up correctly. You should right click on your project > configure > convert to maven project. Then clean up the packages if they turn red.
5. Last thing - you need to add another class called Launcher - and then you start your application from it - do not remove the main method from your main class

package zenit.ui;

public class Launcher {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestUI.main(args);
}
```

}

Hope this helps!

Comment: aaah!!! thank you, removing ikonli helped! Weird tho, since ikonli did work when the project was a regular java project.. any idea why? but, if I set root(this) I get `Root value already specified.` what should I have/not have in the fxml?

Comment: if I remove the `VBox` from the fxml I get `Invalid root element.`

Comment: I wrapped the fxml code in `<fx:root>` , and now, I get no Exceptions, the application is running, but nothing visual appear :/

Comment: sorry for spamming, it works now!! thank you so much you are a legend! <3