# How to set a controller for a fxml file that is in the resources folder of a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, apache-poi

I am trying to develop my first javafx desktop app, but i foud myself in a deadlock.
Firstly the program will read some excel files with sales, then create a database and summarise the total collected for 3 employees.But when i was creating a fxml file for the first scene, no matter what i did the compiler didn't locate the fxml file.
After some research i found out that if i put the fxml inside a resouces folder it would work properly, but fater i had done that now i the fxml file doesn't recognize the Controller using the fx:controller option, probably because it isn't in the same directory anymore. i search some more and found a clue to how to fix it but could quite understand how to do it. in this question [JavaFX and maven: NullPointerException: Location is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000423/javafx-and-maven-nullpointerexception-location-is-required/34239165) it says that it is possible to create a copy of the fxml files using the maven resources plugin Code:

```
<build>
...
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.fxml</include>
        </includes>             
    </resource>
</resources>
...
```

But how can i do this? Where does the fxml files have to be the main directory folder or the resources  folder? If  i alter the data using scene builder of one does the other change as well? Do i need to add this maven resources plugin in the porn.xml?Here is some photos:

[Main - Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gidc.png)

[balanceus.fxml in the resource folder before trying fx:controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duuX0.png)

[running fine put without controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCqtv.png)

[then after add fx:controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hq1R.png)

[it breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az8i6.png)

And here is a link for the git hub with the files and with .txt of the complete error i get when tring to run:

[github](https://github.com/VictorVirgolino/BalanceUSM)

Any Help is appreciated, also sorry for the bad english(not my first language).

Comment: [mcve] please (mind the _M_!) here, not any external resource.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded and analyzed your project and found some mistakes in the structure (and that an “open statement” in the module.info is missing) but after fixing them it still didn't work. :-(

So I created a new project from an archetype as described here:
[Getting Started with JavaFX > JavaFX and IntelliJ > Modular with Maven](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)

When using *„javafx-archetype-fxml“* you will get a basic structure which you need for your project. Then I copied some files of your project to the right places and it looks like this:

[image: project structure]

So as you can see the fxml files don't have to be in the main ressource folder. I put them in a separated folder named fxml.

Then I copied your **App** class and changed it to this:

```
package com.ultrasomma;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(App.class.getResource("fxml/balanceus.fxml")));
        scene.getStylesheets().add(App.class.getResource("css/BalanceUS.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle("BalanceUS");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(App.class.getResource("img/BalanceUS.png").toExternalForm()));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

The **module-info** looks like this (you have to add the other stuff I abstracted from):

```
module com.ultrasomma {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    // This statement is missing in your project:
    opens com.ultrasomma to javafx.fxml;

    exports com.ultrasomma;
}
```

If you do it like this, it should work for you too (no need to manipulate the pom file).

---

I am not sure if I understand this question of yours correctly:

> If i alter the data using scene builder of one does the other change as well?

If you change "balanceus.fxml" then "balanceus2.fxml" will not change.

---

The reference for the controller in your fxml is fine btw.:

```
fx:controller="com.ultrasomma.Controller"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try right away and give some feedback

Comment: anko i finally did it my only prblem now is how to package/deploy the app. i've been trying but nothing works.

Comment: This helped me a lot to create a native installer for deployment with JPackage:  [A tutorial project featuring a build script (Mac, Windows) for JavaFX applications based on the new jpackage tool.](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX)